# Read CSV file into a two dimensional linked list

Tags: java, csv, linked-list

I have a csv file such as the following:

> Mike;Sanders;23
>
> Julie;Walker;45
>
> Frasier;Crane;65

My intention is to read the CSV file so that each item of each row is stored in a linked list such as LinkedListA. I then wish to create a linked list of the linked list of each row.

So for example

> LinkedListA(0) = Mike, LinkedListA(1) = Sanders, LinkedListA(2) = 23
>
> LinkedListB(0) = Julie, LinkedListB(1) = Walker, LinkedListB(2) = 45
>
> LinkedListC(0) = Friasier, LinkedListC(1) = Crane, LinkedListC(2) = 65

AND

> LinkedListD(0)=LinkedListA, LinkedListD(1)=LinkedListB, LinkedListD(2) = LinkedListC

I tried different ways of coding this. The code below resulted in the whole file being saved into one linked list.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
    File file = new File("static.csv");
    String content = new String();
    LinkedList staticmar = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList instatmar = new LinkedList();
    
    try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
    content = sc.nextLine();
    instatmar.add(content);
    }
    sc.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
    fnf.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
    } 
    }
```

I am sure I need to use the scan.useDelimeter(); function somehow.
So my questions are:

1. How do I split each row of my file based on the delimeter and save it into a linkedlist but stop it at the end of the row.
2. Is it wrong that I want to have a linked list of linked lists? My reason for this is I want to use a priorrity queue later on for searching the linked lists.

TIA

Comment: Why do you want to put each row into a `LinkedList`? It seems more logical to create a `Person` class and store the items in it, and then create a list of `Person`.

Comment: Not sure if I undderstand this entirely. If I do as you suggest would I still have a linked list containing all Persons in it? What I want to do it search the list by name, for example 'Frasier' and upon finding the entry I want it to pull out the Surname and Age as part of the results. This is why I want a linked list of linked lists. But there may be a better way!

Comment: If you're always looking people up by name, not by surname or age, then you should have a `Map` rather than a `List`. And using a `Person` class would be a better way, provided you create the class properly, with getters and setters.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Maps, getters or setters I'll need to look them up. However, for this instance I don't have the option of using a Map. I need to chose from one of the following data structures: Linked Lists, Arrays or Trees. I thought that LinkedLists would be best for my situation.

Comment: A LinkedList, then, but the items should be objects. Ask your tutor.

Comment: Haha ... I'm 38 I don't have a tutor :P But thank you for your input :)

Comment: Has nothing to do with age. With the constraints you are presenting, it seems to be a homework question. You can still take courses and do homework when you're 70 years old. If you are self-studying, it's harder, because StackOverflow is not a tutorial community. We can't guide you to proper style and concepts because it's too broad for the site. A forum of some kind is better. I can only tell you that you should have classes here, as related items of information about one entity (name, surname, age, or id, size, color, material, etc.) should be objects.

Comment: The problem is I did something similar to this over 10 years ago in C at the time. I am convinced that would work best for me, because that's basic human psychology you stick to what you know. I am not a student of any kind but I do need to do this in one of the data structures I mentioned. I have been refering to this website for years and I don't think my question is an unreasonable one. Your last comment could be perceived as discouraging which I don't think is in agreement with the spirit of this website. Your recommendation is too vague and my programming too rusty but thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128284/discussion-between-maz-and-realskeptic).